# Removing a semaphore when it has no waits

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency

Here's a concurrency problem:

A string value is used to represent an abstract resource, and only one thread is allowed to work for a given string value; but multiple threads can run concurrently if their string values are different. So far, so simple:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<String,Object> _locks = new Dictionary<String,Object>();

public static void DoSomethingMutuallyExclusiveByName(String resourceName) {

    Object resourceLock;
    lock( _locks ) {

        if( !_locks.TryGetValue( resourceName, out resourceLock ) ) {
            _locks.Add( resourceName, resourceLock = new Object() );
        }
    }

    lock( resourceLock ) {

        EnterCriticalSection( resourceName );
    }
}
```

But this is suboptimal: the domain of `resourceName` is unbounded and `_locks` could end up containing thousands or more strings. So after no more threads are using a specific `resourceName` value then its locking-object should be removed from the dictionary.

It would be a bug to simply remove a lock-object after it has been used, because of this scenario below (with relevant code located further below). Note that all three threads have `resourceName = "foo"`.

- Thread 1 is at `labelC` and has just removed its `resourceName = "foo"` from the `_locks` dictionary thus removing `resourceLock (#1)`.
- Thread 2 is at `labelB`, because no other thread is locked on `resourceLock (#1)` it does not wait at `lock( resourceLock` but instead continues into `EnterCriticalSection`.
- Thread 3 is at `labelA` and because `resourceName = "foo"` is not in `_locks` (because Thread 1 removed it) it adds a new instance to `_locks`, and because this `resourceLock (#2)` is a new instance the `lock( resourceLock )` in thread 3 will not wait for thread 2, consequently both threads 2 and 3 can be inside `EnterCriticalSection` with the same `resourceName` value.

Code:

```
public static void DoSomethingMutuallyExclusiveByName(String resourceName) {

labelA:        
    Object resourceLock;
    lock( _locks ) {

        if( !_locks.TryGetValue( resourceName, out resourceLock ) ) {
            _locks.Add( resourceName, resourceLock = new Object() );
        }
    }

    try {

labelB:
        lock( resourceLock ) {

            EnterCriticalSection( resourceName );
        }
    }
    finally {

        lock( _locks ) {
            _locks.Remove( resourceName );
        }
labelC:
    }

}
```

I initially solved with this my own little hack:

```
class CountedLock {
    public Int32 Count;
}

private static readonly Dictionary<String,CountedLock> _locks = new Dictionary<String,CountedLock>();

public static void DoSomethingMutuallyExclusiveByName(String resourceName) {

labelA:        
    CountedLock resourceLock;
    lock( _locks ) {

        if( !_locks.TryGetValue( resourceName, out resourceLock ) ) {
            _locks.Add( resourceName, resourceLock = new CountedLock() { Count = 1 } );
        }
        else {
            resourceLock.Count++; // no need for Interlocked.Increment as we're already in a mutex code block
        }
    }

    try {

labelB:
        lock( resourceLock ) {

            EnterCriticalSection( resourceName );
        }
    }
    finally {

        lock( _locks ) {
labelD:
            if( --resourceLock.Count == 0 ) {
                _locks.Remove( resourceName );
            }
        }
labelC:
    }

}
```

This solves the problem. Assuming the three threads are at the same locations as before:

- Thread 1 did not remove its `resourceName` `resourceLock` value from `_locks` because Thread 2 also has a reference to the same `resourceLock` as Thread 1, so the associated count was `2` when Thread 1 was at `labelD` (and the count then becomes `1` when Thread 1 reaches `labelC`).
- Thread 2 continues to enter the critical section because it got there before Thread 3.
- If Thread 3 (at `labelA`) gets to `TryGetValue` while Thread 2 is still in the critical section then will see that its `resourceName="foo"` is still in the `_locks` dictionary and so gets the same instance as Thread 2, so it will wait at `labelB` for Thread 2 to complete.
- So this works!

But I imagine now you're thinking:

> "So you have a lock with an associated count... sounds like you just re-invented semaphores. Don't re-invent the wheel, use `System.Threading.Sempahore` or `SemaphoreSlim`.

Indeed, so I changed my code to use a `SemaphoreSlim` - a `SemaphoreSlim` instance has an internal `Count` value which is the number of threads allowed to enter (as opposed to the number of threads currently "inside" the semaphore - which is the opposite to how my `CountedLock` example worked in the previous example):

```
private static readonly Dictionary<String,SemaphoreSlim> _locks = new Dictionary<String,SemaphoreSlim>();

public static void DoSomethingMutuallyExclusiveByName(String resourceName) {

labelA:
    SemaphoreSlim resourceLock;
    lock( _locks ) {
        if( !_locks.TryGetValue( resourceName, out resourceLock ) {
            _locks.Add( resourceName, resourceLock = new SemaphoreLock( initialCount: 1, maxCount: 1 ) );
        }
    }

labelB:
    resourceLock.Wait(); // this decrements the semaphore's count

    try {
        EnterCriticalSection( resourceName );
    }
    finally {

        lock( _locks ) {
            Int32 count = resourceLock.Release(); // this increments the sempahore's count
            if( count > 0 ) {
                _locks.Remove( resourceName );
                resourceLock.Dispose();
            }
labelC:
        }
    }
}
```

...but spot the bug!

Consider this scenario:

- Thread 1 is at `labelC` and just removed and disposed its `resourceLock (#1)` instance.
- Thread 2 is at `labelB` (immediately prior to calling `Wait`). It had acquired a reference to the same `SemaphoreSlim resourceLock (#1)` instance as Thread 1; but because the `Wait` method is called after the thread leaves the `lock( _locks )` under `labelA` it means there is a small, but extant, window-of-opportunity where thread 2 will then call `resourceLock (#1).Wait()` (ignoring the possible `ObjectDisposedException`) while thread 3 (currently at `labelA`) will then enter `TryGetValue` and instantiate a new instance of `SemaphoreLock (#2)` for the same `resourceName`, but because thread 2 and thread 3 have difference semaphore instances they will both potentially enter the critical section simultaneously.

You might suggest:

> You should just find a way to decrement the semaphore while you're inside the `lock( _locks )` block under `labelA`

...except the `SemaphoreSlim` class does not expose any `Decrement` method. You *can* call `.Wait(0)` such that it returns immediately, so my code could look like this:

```
[...]
labelA:
    SemaphoreSlim resourceLock;
    lock( _locks ) {
        if( !_locks.TryGetValue( resourceName, out resourceLock ) {
            _locks.Add( resourceName, resourceLock = new SemaphoreLock( initialCount: 1, maxCount: 1 ) );
        }
        resourceLock.Wait( 0 );
    }

labelB:
    resourceLock.Wait();
[...]
```

...except this won't work. The documentation for `Wait(Int32)` states (emphasis mine):

> If a thread or task is blocked when calling Wait(Int32), and the time-out interval specified by millisecondsTimeout expires, the thread or task doesn’t enter the semaphore, **and the CurrentCount property isn’t decremented**.

...so much for that theory. Even if it did work, calling `Wait` twice in the same thread might perhaps decrement the count twice, not once.

So is it possible to have a critical-section guarded by mutexes that somehow "know" when they're not needed anymore?

Answer (score 3):

I would actually stick with your simpler, count-based solution, rather than `SemaphoreSlim`, since you've already implemented it anyway. While called "slim", `SemaphoreSlim` is nevertheless *less* lightweight than your simple counter. As you are aware, using the semaphore actually makes the code slightly less performant, and a bit more complicated. If nothing else, if it takes more time to convince oneself that this version actually works, then perhaps it's  not the better version.

So, perhaps you are reinventing the wheel, but `SemaphoreSlim` is a general-purpose semaphore, with functionality you don't fully need. Even Microsoft reinvented the wheel by adding `SemaphoreSlim` to the BCL, when `Semaphore` was already there.

On the other hand, if you feel like contention might be an issue with your global lock, you might try using a lockless approach instead. Most likely, you won't have such issues, but if you really think this will be called thousands of times all over your code, you opt for something like:

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, CountedLock> _locks 
    = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CountedLock>();

public static void DoSomethingMutuallyExclusiveByName(string resourceName)
{
    CountedLock resourceLock;

    // we must use a loop to avoid incrementing a stale lock object
    var spinWait = new SpinWait();
    while (true)
    {
        resourceLock = _locks.GetOrAdd(resourceName, i => new CountedLock());
        resourceLock.Increment();

        // check that the instance wasn't removed in the meantime
        if (resourceLock == _locks.GetOrAdd(resourceName, i => new CountedLock()))
            break;

        // otherwise retry
        resourceLock.Decrement();
        spinWait.SpinOnce();
    }

    try
    {
        lock (resourceLock)
        {
            // EnterCriticalSection(resourceName);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (resourceLock.Decrement() <= 0)
            _locks.TryRemove(resourceName, out resourceLock);
    }
}
```

With `CountedLock` also modified to use the `Interlocked` class:

```
class CountedLock
{
    Int32 _count;
    public int Increment() => Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
    public int Decrement() => Interlocked.Decrement(ref _count);
}
```

Either way, I would probably reorganize the code to be generic, and to (ab)use the `IDisposable` interface to allow you to simply wrap the call in a single `using` block.

Answer (score 2):

It seems calling `Wait( 0 )` is actually the solution. Indeed, it does not decrement the sempahore's count if the sempahore is already blocked, so it's just a matter of calling it again with an infinite timeout after we leave the `lock( _locks )` mutex, like so:

```
public static void DoSomethingMutuallyExclusiveByName(String resourceName) {

    Boolean hasLock;
    SemaphoreSlim resourceLock;
    lock( _locks ) {
        if( !_locks.TryGetValue( resourceName, out resourceLock ) {
            _locks.Add( resourceName, resourceLock = new SemaphoreLock( initialCount: 1, maxCount: 1 ) );
        }
        hasLock = resourceLock.Wait( 0 ); // This call will not block. And this call will decrement the semaphore count only if it succeeds (returns true).
    }

    if( !hasLock ) resourceLock.Wait(); // This will block, but will only be called if the previous call to Wait(0) indicated this thread did not enter the semaphore.

    try {
        EnterCriticalSection( resourceName );
    }
    finally {

        lock( _locks ) {
            Int32 count = resourceLock.Release(); // this increments the sempahore's count
            if( count > 0 ) {
                _locks.Remove( resourceName );
                resourceLock.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think this solves the problem - I'm at pain to see a race-condition in this version. The fact that the `Wait(0)` call is inside the `lock( _locks )` mutex means that at least 1 thread for a given `resourceName` will have the lock immediately after the closing brace of the first `lock`, so a semaphore instance will never be removed from the `_locks` collection if either anyone is waiting on it, or is inside the critical section.

Comment: `if( !hasLock ) resourceLock.Wait()` I belive this code might get called after it has been removed from the `_locks`. So it's not thread safe since you have a race condition between finally and the if statement I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, sometimes it might be better to reinvent the wheel.

I'm а fan of the `Monitor` based synchronization constructs (in fact all `Slim` classes use such constructs in one or another way). The first thing that comes to my mind is something simple like this:

```
public class CriticalSectionSlim<TKey>
{
    private readonly HashSet<TKey> lockSet = new HashSet<TKey>();
    public void Enter(TKey key)
    {
        lock (lockSet)
        {
            while (!lockSet.Add(key))
                Monitor.Wait(lockSet);
        }
    }
    public void Exit(TKey key)
    {
        lock (lockSet)
        {
            lockSet.Remove(key);
            Monitor.PulseAll(lockSet);
        }
    }
}
```

The potential performance issue is that (A) there is affinity between the key waiters and (B) the non intelligent pulsing.

A bit more complicated version that solves the (B), thus minimizing the affect of (A) could be as follows:

```
public class CriticalSectionSlim<TKey>
{
    const int EnteredFlag = int.MinValue;
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, int> lockInfo = new Dictionary<TKey, int>();
    public void Enter(TKey key)
    {
        lock (lockInfo)
        {
            int info;
            if (lockInfo.TryGetValue(key, out info))
            {
                if ((info & EnteredFlag) != 0)
                {
                    lockInfo[key] = info + 1;
                    do
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(lockInfo);
                        info = lockInfo[key];
                    }
                    while ((info & EnteredFlag) != 0);
                    info--;
                }
            }
            lockInfo[key] = EnteredFlag | info;
        }
    }
    public void Exit(TKey key)
    {
        lock (lockInfo)
        {
            int waitCount = lockInfo[key] & ~EnteredFlag;
            if (waitCount == 0)
                lockInfo.Remove(key);
            else
            {
                lockInfo[key] = waitCount;
                Monitor.PulseAll(lockInfo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For each key, we keep a flag if it's entered and also the count of waiters if any. This allows us to avoid pulsing on exit if there are no waiters.

Comment: First snippet is really simple, doesn't seem to have any race conditions, so I would prefer this approach for most "reasonable" applications, although pulsing all waiting threads (regardless of the actual key that's been released) is less than optimal. But since the second example involves reference counting, I wouldn't say it's a radical improvement over OP's code. To be honest, I am not sure what's the point of `EnteredFlag` once the key is in the dictionary (you never clear this flag)?

Comment: @Lousy Imagine there is one thread owning the key and two threads waiting for that key. When the owner thread releases the key and does pulse, both waiters will wake up, so only one of them should enter, while the other should continue waiting.

Comment: Ok, I get it, you don't call `PulseAll` unless there is at least one thread waiting for this key (although again all threads get pulsed, regardless of the actual key they are waiting on). I wonder if there exists a solution using a `ConcurrentDictionary` with per-key token which would allow wait/pulse for only a single token (i.e pulsing a single key only), of course without introducing race conditions.